# How to generate APN certificate so that it should handle to support both old as well as new application after ios app transfer

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apn

I have transferd my ios app from my account(AA) to client account(BB).for push notification in fire-base server we uploaded APN (private key) which is generated by AA. But now account is changed and also i am updating app with new account. So if i upload new APN generate from new account, older app will not support push notification. But however i read like " we can generate a APN which will support older and new app"

But how to achieve that..?

With old APN i tried to push notifn to new app which is signed/updated with new account i.e BB , notification is failing..

Comment: it will exist know
transfer will not impact on store app

Comment: So there will be no impact on App store, therefore you don't need to create APNS certificate for older app. For App transfer, it may take time to reflect to trasfer app from older account to newer one.

Comment: its already done ..meaning available in newer(BB) account.
now i want to upload from new account(BB) so i have to create new apn certificate 
if i create and upload new APN from new account(BB) to firebase older app will not receive push notification 

is there any way to handle like new apn should support old as well as new ??

Comment: There is no dependency or conflict between the Live application and creating new APNS certificate. If you creating new APNS certificate, you have to configure it with backend only when you have to submit an application through new (BB) account.

Comment: Your current application will receive push notifications regardless of new APNS certificate in your new (BB) account.

Comment: but fire-base account is same for me ..i have to replace the previous APN(private key) with the new one(which i created with new account BB)

Comment: Yes, there will be no issue of it. If you sending notification with newly created APNS certificate, it will only receive in the build with the same certificate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194045/discussion-between-sunilkumar-godi-and-bhavik-modi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are creating a new APNS certificate in (BB) account and you have to make your application live, in that case, you have to update application and firebase certificate with latest APNS.
2. Your existing application will have no impact, if you are creating new APNS certificate or not, it will work without any fail - *until you update the APNS to Firebase server*

   Note: If you change Push notification certificate in backend server / Firebase server, your existing live application won't receive any push notification.

Answer (score 0):

[https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012284-Transfer-your-app-to-another-iOS-Developer-Account][1]

I think its support you for move application one account to another